# Taking away from numpy ndarray from another

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two `numpy.ndarrays` which one is a random sample from the other. I wish to take the smaller one (random sample) and remove those data points from the larger one.

What is the code to do so?

- delete and remove do not work on ndarrays

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```py
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1])
b = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
np.setdiff1d(a, b) # array([1, 2])
```

From [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html).

Comment: I have 800 random samples from the "a" data set, I am unsure of their indexes, is there a line of code to find this?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I've edited